# Add an underscore after every Occurrence of Capital Letter followed by number

Tags: bash

In bash i want to replace

```
 H+O2=O+OH
```

with

```
H+O_2=O+OH
```

I tried countless things with awk and sed but nothing worked so far.
The Problem is that i dont know how to save the string and then just add the `_` instead of replacing the `O` or the `2`.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
$> s='H+O2=O+OH'
$> sed -E 's/([A-Z])([0-9])/\1_\2/g' <<< "$s"
H+O_2=O+OH
```

Comment: can you explain to me how the string is saved in sed ? does it has something to do with 1_?

Comment: `\1` is back-reference for first captured group i.e. `([A-Z])` and `\2` is back-reference for the second captured group i.e. `([0-9])`

Comment: so just to get it right:
sed 's/(regex1)(regex2)/\1_\2/g'

Comment: sorry im pressing enter too much...
sed 's/(regex1)(regex2)/\1_\2/g'
means replace following occurence of regex1 and regex2 with regex1 followed by _ and regex 2? the backslashes before the 1 and 2 are for escaping?

Comment: `\N` is syntax used by sed's regex engine for denoting back-references. [See this table for all the details](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)

Answer (score 0):

If Perl is an option, you can use a technique very similar to Anubhava's:

`echo 'H+O2=O+OH' | perl -pe 's/([A-Z])([0-9])/\1_\2/g'`

Comment: `\d` can be used instead of `[0-9]` in perl... so `perl -pe 's/([A-Z])(\d)/\1_\2/g'` or even `perl -pe 's/([A-Z])(?=\d)/\1_/g'`